# How to add HTML tags around text contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, find

I have a paragraph with 2 or more tags:

```
<p>#tag1 #tag2</p>
```

Now I want to find all tags and wrap them like this:

```
<p><span class="someClass">#tag1</span> <span class="someClass">#tag2</span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.html()` with the callback that passes the current value and use the regex:

```
#\w+\b
```

which means: match any word that starts with a #

```js
$("p").html(function(index, html) { 
        return html.replace(/(\#\w+\b)/g, "<span>$1</span>") 
       });
```

```css
span { color: orange }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>#tag1 #tag2</p>
<p>Here's another #tag3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('p:contains("#")').each(function() {
    var tags = $(this).text().split(' ');
    var wrapped_tags = '';

    tags.forEach(function(tag) {
      wrapped_tags += '<span class="someClass">'+tag+'</span> ';
    });

    $(this).html(wrapped_tags);
});
```

```css
.someClass {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>#tag1 #tag2</p>
```

Comment: This will also wrap non "tags" (though not clear in the question if there are only tags or mixed)

Comment: @freedomn-m yep, i assume that op mean there is many pharagraps and some of them have only tags inside

Comment: @freedomn-m anyway your answer is better

Comment: @Sojtin thanks, but there's always scope for a looping version.  Some of the jquery commands (like map and the html(callback) here and also regex) can be less-than-obvious, and having a more explicit version can be beneficial.